# meaning of 'pitch' here

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from [a news article](https://apnews.com/article/abortion-north-carolina-governor-veto-rally-52f5b182890d44552a3287dee2aaf5b3) :

> Republicans have **pitched** the measure as a middle-ground change to
> state abortion laws developed after months of private negotiations
> between House and Senate GOP members. It adds exceptions to the
> 12-week ban, extending the limit through 20 weeks for rape and incest
> and through 24 weeks for “life-limiting” fetal anomalies.

I looked up the verb '**pitch**' in [the Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch#dictionary-entry-2) :

> 3a : to present or advertise especially in a high-pressure way : PLUG,
> PROMOTE
>
> 4a(1) : to cause to be at a particular level or of a particular
> quality

Although there aren't any adverbial phrases denoting a certain level, I think 'middle-ground' and 'adds exceptions' make the '**pitched**' seem to mean 4a(1) more likely, despite the opposing positions of the parties which may suggest 3a.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Meaning 4a(1) is usually "pitched at". Meaning 3a is usually "pitched as". This example is "pitched as".

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much.

Comment: No, pitched here means plugged or promoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most appropriate definition here is actually more like 3b or a metaphorical use of 3c:

> b: attempt to persuade especially with a sales pitch
> c
> : to present (a movie or program idea) for consideration (as by a TV producer)

My reading of the sentence is that the Republicans are *presenting* this idea, as a compromise which would make it more appealing.  *Pitch*, in the context of proposed legislation, almost always means to present or to attempt to "sell" something.  For example,

- [Senate pitches classification reform in light of Pentagon leaks, White House documents](https://thehill.com/policy/national-security/3998246-senate-pitches-classification-reform-in-light-of-pentagon-leaks-white-house-documents/)
- [McCarthy’s pitch to shrink food aid drawing skepticism from fellow Republicans](https://www.politico.com/news/2023/04/16/gop-mccarthy-snap-food-stamps-00092243)
- [Wisconsin's Rep. Moore pitches bipartisanship as dean of state delegation](https://www.ny1.com/nyc/all-boroughs/politics/2023/01/06/rep--moore-pitches-bipartisanship-as-dean-of-delegation)
  etc.

I understand why "as a middle-ground change" makes it sound like 4a1 might be appropriate, but *pitched* in this sense, where it means "at a particular level or quality" is almost always used with *at*:

> [A tuning fork that belonged to Ludwig van Beethoven around 1800, now in the British Library, is pitched at A = 455.4 Hz...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concert_pitch#Pre-19th_century)

> [With a dfficulty pitched at "Close To Impossible"...](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1883011/6-out-10-dfficulty-pitched-close-impossible-and-no)

> [Since this was the advanced course, one hoped that it would be pitched at a high level, and it was.](https://rarebookschool.org/2000/summer/evaluations/42_noble.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and kind explanation.